# 404 server redirect, or some other method?

Tags: php, apache, http, concept

I would like to know how to handle a problem which I guess is somewhat generic. But i am just not sure how it is supposed to be done. So hopefully people can find the way around what may be ill formed thoughts and bad terminology.

I did a tinyurl-like service just as an example, nothing which should be actually used. It's written in php and uses mysql. All well it's only one problem I couldn't really figure out, and I feel like I've run into this before.

The problem is when expanding the generated url (for simplicity let's assume that the base url is `http://a.com` and that the links are ordered by an auto-incremental index so i just give the database index when giving a tinified url.

For tinyurl a link would be for example: `http://tinyurl/abcd`

I however used a parameter and end up doing something like `http://q.com?u=0`

I guess that if I want to have a format like the first one I could set up .httaccess in my apache server to use a custom 404 page so when going to: `http://a.com/0` I would actually get a 404, redirected to my own 404.php and in that page handle the database lookup and redirect to the real url.

My problem is that I just have this gut feeling that using 404 as a "feature" is a bit dirty. And my question is if this would be the general way to do it, or if there are some other ways which I just don't know about.

Sorry for the rant and thanks for any information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at mod_rewrite!
In your .htaccess File you could do something like this:
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?u=$1`

That might not be the best rule, but there are plenty tutorials out there!

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Sometimes the problem is only as hard as your own lack of knowledge I guess.. Thank you very much I am happy that you understood what I asked for :P I weren't sure if I made it clear enough.